# Play store console displaying release not live

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

We push the app into production app version name "1.0.2" and after again we push the app into open testing version name "1.0.3" then after some time it displays "release not live" for open testing

reference for open testing app

[image]

reference for production app

[image]

and we set "Managed publishing status" as "Managed publishing on"

[image]

My question is :

1. If Managed publishing Off then what happened
2. if we send and review button click then what happened

[image]

Comment: Did you find any update?

Comment: 1. If you set managed publishing to "Managed publishing off" your app will be released to the track after completion of its review. So, when you click "Start rollout to [TRACK]", the app goes into review, then will immediately start to roll out on that track. 

As for "if we send and review button click then what happened" I'm not sure exactly what you mean, could you please clarify?